# Are there any techniques that can be used in the case when a Neumann series doesn't converge?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sequences-and-series, operator-theory, taylor-series

Suppose we have a bounded linear operator $A = A(\gamma):H_1\to H_2$ where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hilbert spaces and $\gamma>0$ is some parameter, and we are interested in the solution to
$$
(I-A)x = y.
$$
If $\|A\|<1$ we can use a Neumann series expansion and get a series representation:
\begin{align}
x & = (I-A)^{-1} y \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^\infty A^j y
\end{align}

Now, suppose that when $\gamma$ becomes small enough $\|A(\gamma)\|$ becomes greater than $1$ and the Neumann series won't converge; thus we can't get a series representation for $x$.

An example of this situation can be found in problems featuring scattering of waves among disjoint objects. If the solution is represented as a Neumann series, it can fail to converge if frequencies become high or if distances between objects become small.

Are any techniques that can used in such a situation to 'get around' the non-convergence of a Neumann series and obtain a series representation for $x$?

Comment: You would still win if the spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$. If the spectral radius of $A$ is $\geq 1$ then $I$ might be in the spectrum of $A$ and then there is no hope of defining $(I-A)^{-1}$ as a bounded operator

Comment: BTW you have $I+A$ at one point and $I-A$ on the next line; I assume one of these is a typo?

Comment: For symmetric operators [Hilbert Space and the Padé Approximant](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S007653920862682X), non-paywalled [Google Books preview](https://books.google.ca/books?id=kif3E81LXnsC&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=%22method+of+moments%22+selfadjoint+resolvent&source=bl&ots=HVsZUwKmGA&sig=ACfU3U0bzPVj1g5QgnwDLDctKrtQkeHang&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8pY-H6PfnAhUXvZ4KHeBYBo4Q6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22method%20of%20moments%22%20selfadjoint%20resolvent&f=false) starting p.197 . Not a "series representation".

Comment: @KeithMcClary I have seen Pade approximants mentioned in the context of accelerating the convergence a Neumann series but I didn't know they can also work when a Neumann series doesn't converge. So I'll take a look into this, although I am dealing with non-symmetric operators so maybe it can't be applied to my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the spectrum of $A$ is contained in a disk $\{z: |z - a| \le r\}$ where $|1-a| > r$, then the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-a)^{-1-n} (A - a I)^n$ converges to $(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, one only has a chance if $1$ is not in the spectrum of $A$.

Robert Israel's answer gives a series that converges to the resolvent $(I-A)^{-1}$ if the spectrum of $A$ is, for instance, contained in a disk with radius larger then $1$, but centered sufficiently far in the left half plane.

Another method to obtain a series representation for $(I-A)^{-1}$ is based on the following fact:

**Proposition.** Let $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$ be in the resolvent set of $A$ and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ be a number such that $|\lambda - \mu| < \frac{1}{\|(\mu I - A)^{-1}\|}$. Then $\lambda$ is also in the resolvent set of $A$ and the resolvent of $A$ at $\lambda$ is given by
$$
(\lambda I - A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\mu - \lambda)^k (\mu I - A)^{-(k+1)}.
$$
*Proof.* This follows readily from the Neumann series expansion if we use that
$$
\lambda I - A = (\lambda - \mu) I + \mu I - A = (\mu I - A)^{-1}\Big( I - (\mu - \lambda)(\mu I - A) \Big).
$$

If one is interested in the case $\lambda = 1$, but the spectral radius of $A$ is $\ge 1$, one could for instance try the following procedure:

Choose a real number $r > r(A)$ (where $r(A)$ denotes the spectral radius) and use the Neumann series to compute $(rI - A)^{-1}$. In case that the interval $[1,r]$ is in the resolvent set of $A$, one can now move a bit left of $r$ and compute the resolvent at this new point by means of the above proposition. Then, again, one can move a bit more left, and iterate this procedure until one arrives at $1$. Thus, one obtains a "representation" of $(I - A)^{-1}$ by means of a finitely often iterated series expansion.

Whether this is useful or not depends of course on the application one has in mind. Sometimes this (or a related) technique can be quite useful for theoretical purposes; on the other hand, I would suspect that the procedure is completely unsuited for, say, numerical computations.

Comment: Nice! Does this approach still work if the spectrum is say the unit circle and you want a series for some of the resolvent which is inside the unit circle?